# How do I create a "filter by price" type of query?

Tags: sql, filtered-lookup

I'm using VBScript (ASP Classic) and SQL Server; I'm trying to have a section on the website where you can see a count of products at certain price levels.  Something like:

```
$50 - $100 (4)
$100 - $500 (198)
$500 - $1000 (43)
```

For the love of me I cannot figure out a good way to do a query like this.  I mean... I know how to get the number of products at a certain price range, but I can't figure out how to do it at several different price ranges without having to write a boatload of nested queries to aggregate all the results, especially since the price ranges can differ greatly among related products.

Is there a "rule of thumb" when doing something like this as to how you figure out the different price ranges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way of doing this in SQL (I believe) is to use a `sum case` construct:

```
select  sum(case when Price >= 50 and Price < 100 then 1 else 0 end) as 50to100,
        sum(case when Price >= 100 and Price < 500 then 1 else 0 end) as 100to500,
        sum(case when Price >= 500 and Price < 1000 then 1 else 0 end) as 500to1000
from    Products
```

This will only require a single scan of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Table drive it:

```
SELECT pr.MinPrice, pr.MaxPrice, COUNT(*)
FROM Products AS p
INNER JOIN PriceRanges AS pr
    ON p.UnitPrice BETWEEN pr.MinPrice AND pr.MaxPrice
GROUP BY pr.MinPrice, pr.MaxPrice
ORDER BY pr.MinPrice, pr.MaxPrice
```

If you need different price ranges for different product categories:

```
SELECT pr.ProductCategory, pr.MinPrice, pr.MaxPrice, COUNT(*)
FROM Products AS p
INNER JOIN PriceRanges AS pr
    ON p.ProductCategory = pr.ProductCategory
    AND p.UnitPrice BETWEEN pr.MinPrice AND pr.MaxPrice
GROUP BY pr.ProductCategory, pr.MinPrice, pr.MaxPrice
ORDER BY pr.ProductCategory, pr.MinPrice, pr.MaxPrice
```

You will have to add some cleanup and handle the end of the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You could use union queries

```
SELECT '100 - 200', COUNT(*) FROM Products
WHERE Price >= 100 AND Price <= 200
UNION
SELECT '300 - 400', COUNT(*) FROM Products
WHERE Price >= 300 AND Price <= 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function (UDF) that relates price range with a value

```
$50 - $100 = 1
$100 - $500 = 2
$500 - $1000 = 3
```

etc.

Then do a select grouping by the function on the value column.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use a SQL function which assigned each record with a category code based on the value, and then group by the category code with a count.